# Eclipse 3.0 for php not stopping at breakpoint,

Tags: php, eclipse, iis, xdebug

I am running on eclipse 3,0 with
Zend Engine v4.0.3,
with Xdebug v3.0.3
and Php 8.0.3

This is in php.ini:

xdebug.idekey=ECLIPSE_DBGP
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.client_enable=On
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.client_handler=dbgp
xdebug.client_enable=on
xdebug.client_connect_back=0
xdebug.client_autostart=on
xdebug.start_with_request=yes

Running phpinfo() show XDEBUG running, but with
Step Debugger disabled and Tracing disabled
Port number in eclipse se set to 9003 also

I suspect that is the reason why debugger wont stop at breakpoints
Could be? And how can I enabled them

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mode does not include `debug`, as a matter of fact, you're not setting any `xdebug.mode` setting. If you want to step-debug, you need to set it to `xdebug.mode=debug`.

Also:

`xdebug.client_enable` and `xdebug.client_autostart` aren't settings. And if you're showing `xdebug_info()` output (and not `phpinfo()` as you're saying), then it will also tell you slightly further down whether Xdebug tried to connect to your IDE, and why it wasn't successful.

Comment: Thanks Derick!, I set xdebug.mode=debug and now it is working!  
I do not know how to thank you enough!

Comment: It is my first time sorry. I sure will do. But i do not see how...

Comment: @user2126958, There is a tick under the vote button, click on it to accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry but i do not see any vote button.... May be I do not have permission? Can you send a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the picture example, Click the tick button:

[image]